# How to get a record from two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table name Vouchers in which i have three columns named "GroupName","LedgerName" and "Amount".

[image]

I have another Table named Accounts in which i have two columns "Name" and "Amount", now i want the column "Name" to have the the GroupName from the Vouchers Table and then all the LedgerName that have same GroupName to fall under that Record. The images explain my question asked above

[image]

Comment: How the two tables are linked?? Did you give it a try by yourself?/

Comment: No i havent gave it a try

Answer (score -1):

Isn't this `ORDER BY` operation??

I don't think you can get your result in that format. But using ORDER BY operation you can get a similar output but with an extra column. :)

Comment: say u have your table like this,
Groupname    LedgerName    Amount
cash         Mz            100
cash         Amit          200
test         Murtaza       300
cash         Rumesh        100

SELECT * FROM tbl_name ORDER BY 'Groupname';

will give you 

Groupname    LedgerName    Amount
cash         Mz            100
cash         Amit          200
cash         Rumesh        100
test         Murtaza       300

Comment: SELECT * FROM tbl_name ORDER BY 'Groupname'

Comment: Ok thanx, but i need another result not like this one